# Use both navigation controller and tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, toolbar

I use navigation controller to push my views. Like this:

```
func showDetailForCategory(product: Category){

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let categoryViewController =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "categoryDetail") as! CategoryViewController
    
    categoryViewController.categoryId = product.id
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryViewController, animated:true)
    
}
```

It works just fine. But i want to use toolbar too. My `AppDelegate` is like below

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let featuredAppsController = FeaturedAppsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: featuredAppsController)
    
    let vc1 = featuredAppsController
    vc1.tabBarItem.title = "Orange"
    vc1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "heart")
    
    // Set up the second View Controller
    let vc2 = UIViewController()
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    vc2.tabBarItem.title = "Purple"
    vc2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    
    // Set up the Tab Bar Controller to have two tabs
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
    
    // Make the Tab Bar Controller the root view controller
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I added `TabBarController`. It works fine. But my `NavigationController` doesn't work. I think that is because I set `rootViewController` for two of them. How should i solve this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
let firstVc = UIViewController()
let secondVc = UIViewController()

let firstNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVc)
let secondNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVc)

let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
tabBarController.viewControllers = [firstNav, secondNav]

window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

of course, fill in your classes and whatnot but the basic idea is this

Comment: still my navigation bar doesn't work. i use navigationbar controller to push views when i press a button or something. now, only toolbar controller works.

Comment: you should see two tabs at the bottom and each tab has one view in it. Check if you are hiding the navigationBars programatically, if not, check if you push a new controller on one of the navigationbar, what happens. If nothing, then something big is happening as it should be very simple and working out of the box.